# MySQL equivalent of MS SQL's TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb

I'm migrating my data from `SQLSERVER` to `MySQL`. I'm having some trouble in finding an alternate function for `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()`.

What is the equivalent of `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()` `SQLSERVER` function in `MySQL`
(triggers when recursion is over). If it doesn't have one, how can I detect if the recursion was over in another way?

Here is my query:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_UPD_NAME] 
ON [dbo].[TBL_MS_NAME] FOR UPDATE,INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 1 )
    RETURN

    /* SOME UPDATE QUERY */
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql does not do recursion. Period.

From the from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> - Stored functions cannot be used recursively.
> - Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Comment: Ok, got it. Trying to remove that code in mysql, and it works.